# Adding 'sep=$' to multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, delimiter

I have ~800 CSV files, the problem is that the Delimiter in each of them is '$'.

Is there a way to add the line 'sep=$' to each file, or change the delimiter on these without having to go through each individually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the problem? When you read the files just use `$` as the specified delimiter .

Answer (score 0):

To read a csv file in python delimited by $:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep = '$') //Use pandas.read_csv method
```

To convert a csv file delimited by $ to ,:

```py
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("example.csv", "r"), delimiter='$')
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'), delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(reader)
```